# How to save an array that contains information from a created class using UserDefaults

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I have created an application that is used to show users the newest and top country songs. I use Firebase Databases to send and receive the information for songs. This is in Xcode using Swift and UIKit.

I created a class called Song that handles all the information that I get from Firebase. That class is below.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Song {

//private var _imageURL: String!
private var _videoURL: NSMutableURLRequest!
private var _songTitle: String!
private var _artistName: String!
private var _cellNum: Int!
private var _lastNum: Int!
private var _spotifyLink: String!
private var _itunesLink: String!
private var _lyrics: String!
private var _saved: Bool!

//    var imageURL: String{
//        return _imageURL
//    }

var videoURL: NSMutableURLRequest{
    return _videoURL
}

var songTitle: String{
    return _songTitle
}

var artistName: String{
    return _artistName
}

var cellNum: Int{
    return _cellNum
}

var lastNum: Int{
    return _lastNum
}

var spotifyLink: String{
    return _spotifyLink
}

var itunesLink: String{
    return _itunesLink
}

var lyrics: String{
    return _lyrics
}

var saved: Bool{
    get{
        return _saved
    }
    set{
        _saved = newValue
    }
}

init(videoURL: NSMutableURLRequest, songTitle: String, artistName: String, cellNum: Int, lastNum: Int, spotifyLink: String, itunesLink: String, lyrics: String, saved: Bool) {

    //_imageURL = imageURL
    _videoURL = videoURL
    _songTitle = songTitle
    _artistName = artistName
    _cellNum = cellNum
    _lastNum = lastNum
    _spotifyLink = spotifyLink
    _itunesLink = itunesLink
    _lyrics = lyrics
    _saved = saved
}
}
```

Within one of my swift files, I initialized a new array of type Song to hold the information in which the user saves.

```
var savedSongs = [Song]()
```

There is a button within one of the storyboards that if the user clicks it, it adds the saved song to the array and when the user goes to the SavedVC storyboard, all of the items that are saved in the array are shown to the user. The function for clicking the button is shown below.

```
@IBAction func save(_ sender: Any) {


    if(saveBtn.currentTitle == "Save"){

        song.saved = true
        let p1 = song
        savedSongs.append(p1)
        //UserDefaults save here
        saveBtn.setTitle("Unsave", for: .normal)
    }
    else if(saveBtn.currentTitle == "Unsave"){

        if(savedSongs.count != 0){
            //let items = (savedSongs.count) - 1

            let title = song.songTitle

            for save in 0...savedSongs.count-1{

                let removeSave = savedSongs[save]
                let checkTitle = removeSave.songTitle

                if(checkTitle == title){
                    song.saved = false
                    savedSongs.remove(at: save)
                    //UserDefaults save here
                    saveBtn.setTitle("Save", for: .normal)
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So obviously, the user has an option to save, and after that, he can re-click the button to unsave the song. Within the code, the object

```
song.(attribute)
```

is sent in and is the representation of the cell that is selected that contains the information from the Song class. As I have my code right now, everything works. The problem is that when I leave the app, what is in the array doesn't stay. I have tried UserDefaults, but I am not sure how to do it with the array I have.

I would like to save the array to user defaults every time the button is clicked within the save IBAction above.

Comment: Private backing variables to get constants are ridiculous in Swift. Just use the `let` keyword e.g. `let songTitle: String`. And never ever declare variables as implicit unwrapped optionals which are initialized with an (non-optional) `init` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode and decode the objects in order to save them to UserDefaults.

```
class Song: NSObject, NSCoding {
    let name: String
    let url: String

    init(name: String, url: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.url = url
    }

    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        self.name = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String ?? ""
        self.url = decoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "url") as? String ?? ""
    }

    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
        coder.encode(age, forKey: "url")
    }
}
```

And then to retrieve and save :

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // SAVE TO DEFAULTS
        let song = Song(name: "Song", url: "http://song.com")
        var songs = [Song]()
        songs.append(song)
        let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: songs)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "songs")

        // RETRIEVE FROM DEFAULTS
        if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "songs"),
            let mySongs = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? [Song] {
            mySongs.forEach({print( $0.name, $0.url)})
        } else {
            print("ERROR")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The encoder encodes always both non-optional values. Why do you check for `nil`? This is never going to happen.